# Reverse the output in a script that reads data in an external xml file

Tags: php, phpexcel, reverse

I have a script that reads values in an external XML file using PHPExcel.php, then it prints results reading the last time a number is $extraset is found into the XML file.

My problem : i should **reverse** the way the script calculates the result, since my values go from the newer to the older.
**Example :** if the 10 value appears in row 2 and then in row 6, correct result should be : 10 appears in row 2. At the moment I get '10 appears in row 10'.

Is there a way to reverse the way phpexcel read the file ? Or maybe i can just reverse the way values are processed ? Here is the script :

```
<?php

require_once "Classes/PHPExcel.php";

$path = "original_source.xls";
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($path);
$excel_Obj = $reader->load($path);

//Get the last sheet in excel
//$worksheet=$excel_Obj->getActiveSheet();

//Get the first sheet in excel
$worksheet=$excel_Obj->getSheet('0');

$lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
$columncount = $worksheet->getHighestDataColumn();
$columncount_number = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($columncount);

$row_start = 6;
$row_end = 26;
$col_start = 2; //Index of column - C
$col_end = 21; //Index of column - V

$sets = array();
for ($row = 0; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
    $set = array();
    for ($col = 0; $col <= $columncount_number; $col++) {
        if ($row >= $row_start && $row <= $row_end && $col >= $col_start && $col <= $col_end) {
            array_push($set, $worksheet->getCell(PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($col).$row)->getValue());
        }
        else if ($row > $row_end) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($row >= $row_start && $row <= $row_end) {
        array_push($sets, $set);
    }
    else if ($row > $row_end) {
        break;
    }
}

//echo '<pre>'; print_r($sets); die;



$extraset = ['113', '15', '313'];

$reverse_sets = array_reverse($sets);
foreach ($extraset as $element) {
    foreach ($reverse_sets as $index => $set) {
        if (in_array($element, $set)) {
            $actual_index = count($reverse_sets)-$index-1;
            echo "Extraset element '$element' is in set $actual_index<br>";
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I was trying with **array_reverse**, but I only keep getting 'error 500'. I'm a bit confused.
Thanks for your help

**EDIT :**

The modify i did with array reverse was to remove the array reverse function, changing that part in this way, and it works properly :

```
foreach ($extraset as $element) {
    foreach ($sets as $index => $set) {
        if (in_array($element, $set)) {
            $actual_index = count($sets)-$index-1;
            echo "Extraset element '$element' is in set $actual_index<br>";
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Now the script outputs me the right value, but what I can't fix is the way $actual_index works.
**This is my actual output :**
Extraset element '113' is in set 0
Extraset element '15' is in set 20
Extraset element '313' is in set 20

**My problem :**
The way it search the values is correct, but is wrong the way it calculates the set. Set 0 should be set 20, while set 20 should be set 0.

Comment: A 500 error is just an indications something went wrong.  You should enable (or just log) errors to see what the actual problem is.

Comment: Hi Nigel, yes i did it, there was a problem in the code. I fixed it. I removed the reverse_set function and now it works in the way it search for the values. I still have an output problem, probably connected to $actual_index. I have just edited my question, in case you want to take a look